# Resolving an error when using Create Feature Class using Arcpy

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to run the "Create Feature Class" tool in arcpy but am getting an error on the last line of this script.  As a note, I'm following along with a tutorial from this site (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmxPRK-eomk&list=PLO6KswO64zVt8YCuKIOdCsJvlUivXETGu&index=17).  The script will create one geodatabase, but then when it goes to execute the arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass portion of the code, it gives me the following error:

**ERROR 000732: Feature Class Location: Dataset C:\Users\Data\File_GDB\fgdb_0.gdb does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CreateFeatureclass).**

This is the code I'm attempting to use:

```
import arcpy
import os

working_directory = r"C:\Users\Data\File_GDB"


for fgdb in range(2):
    fgdb_full_path = os.path.join(f"{working_directory}", f"fgdb_{fgdb}.gdb")
        
    arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(f"{working_directory}", f"fdgb_{fgdb}", "CURRENT")

    arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(fgdb_full_path, "fc_1", "POINT", None, "DISABLED", "DISABLED", None, '', 0, 0, 0, '')
```

Comment: You create a geodatabase with the file name `fgdb_0`... you forgot the extension. `f"fdgb_{fgdb}"` should be `f"fdgb_{fgdb}.gdb"`.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the reply.  I tried your suggestion of adding the .gdb to the end of the path, but still the same result.  It creates just one of the GDBs, then the error happens when trying to create the feature class.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if I had a minor typo in the output name of the gdb.  I had `f"fdgb_{fgdb}"` instead of `f"fgdb_{fgdb}"`

Comment: Tip: Try to avoid [magic numbers](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMagicLiteral.html)... so you can avoid bugs like this in future.